# mongoid bulk operation - initialize_unordered_bulk_op

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How to achieve unordered bulk operations using mongoid?
[mongo_unordered_bulk_write](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Bulk-Write-Operations#unordered-bulk-write-operation)

```
bulk = coll.initialize_unordered_bulk_op
bulk.insert({'_id' => 1})
bulk.insert({'_id' => 1}) # duplicate key
bulk.insert({'_id' => 3})
bulk.insert({'_id' => 3}) # duplicate key
bulk.execute
```

Answer (score 2):

Mongoid classes have a `.collection` accessor that gives access to the [`Collection`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html) object from the core driver:

```
bulk = Class.collection.initialize_unordered_bulk_op
```

And so on.

But it is generally preferred in modern drivers to use the more consistent [`bulk_write()`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#bulk_write-instance_method) method and arrays of standard objects:

```
 ops = [];

 ops.push({ "insert_one" => { "_id" => 1 } })
 ops.push({ "insert_one" => { "_id" => 1 } })
 ops.push({ "insert_one" => { "_id" => 3 } })
 ops.push({ "insert_one" => { "_id" => 3 } })

 Class.collection.bulk_write(ops,{ "ordered" => false })
```

Or even [`insert_many()`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#insert_many-instance_method) if you are just doing insertions and not mixing types of write operations:

```
 Class.collection.insert_many([
     { "_id" => 1 },
     { "_id" => 1 },
     { "_id" => 3 },
     { "_id" => 3 }
 ],{ "ordered" => false })
```